# tensor vector dot product in matlab

Tags: inner-products, tensor-products, matlab, tensors

If $A$ is a second rank tensor like  Cauchy stress tensor (I store it in a 3 by 3 matrix) and $v$ is a 3 by 1 vector,

- How can I calculate dot product $A.v$ in Matlab? Can I simply write $A*v$ ?
- What about if i want to calculate $A.B$, where $B$ is another rank 2 tensor, stored in a 3 by 3 matrix.

Thanks

Comment: The answer to this question depends on how you store the data in the matrix (and I assume that you've chosen bases for your spaces).  The answer to the question can be as simple as matrix-vector and matrix-matrix multiplication.

Comment: Thanks. How can i find out if the tensor is stored such that it can be used for the matrix-matrix product? e.g., if we have a stress tensor in a cartesian system(we have x y z columns and rows) can we use the matrix-matrix or matric-vector multiplication of matlab?

Comment: Some example code, what you've tried, and what answers you expect might be helpful.